# Array values changed after looping it in empty foreach

Tags: php, arrays, loops, foreach

I have an array **$export** created from SQL query that I later formatted a little bit. The array now looks like this (these are the last 2 arrays of the whole array)

```
    [6136] => Array
        (
            [id_product] => 247
            [product_name] => Verte Home - vzor B.7.
            [id_attribute] => 181
            [attribute_name] => Premium - Drážka - Tloušťka J (260-280mm)
            [price] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            ["id_attribute"] => 181
                            ["id_custo_group"] => "1"
                            ["price_impact"] => 4099.173554
                        )

                    [1] => Array
                        (
                            ["id_attribute"] => 181
                            ["id_custo_group"] => "2"
                            ["price_impact"] => 4099.173554
                        )

                    [2] => Array
                        (
                            ["id_attribute"] => 181
                            ["id_custo_group"] => "3"
                            ["price_impact"] => 4099.173554
                        )

                )

        )

    [6137] => Array
        (
            [id_product] => 247
            [product_name] => Verte Home - vzor B.7.
            [id_attribute] => 182
            [attribute_name] => Premium - Drážka - Tloušťka K (280-300mm)
            [price] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            ["id_attribute"] => 182
                            ["id_custo_group"] => "1"
                            ["price_impact"] => 4099.173554
                        )

                    [1] => Array
                        (
                            ["id_attribute"] => 182
                            ["id_custo_group"] => "2"
                            ["price_impact"] => 4099.173554
                        )

                    [2] => Array
                        (
                            ["id_attribute"] => 182
                            ["id_custo_group"] => "3"
                            ["price_impact"] => 4099.173554
                        )

                )

        )
```

But if I now put it into this foreach loop and let only the nested **price** array be printed out

```
foreach ($export as $attribute){
        echo '<pre>';
        echo print_r($attribute['price']);
        echo '</pre>';
}
```

I get this (again, last 2 arrays of the whole array)

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            ["id_attribute"] => 181
            ["id_custo_group"] => "1"
            ["price_impact"] => 4099.173554
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            ["id_attribute"] => 181
            ["id_custo_group"] => "2"
            ["price_impact"] => 4099.173554
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            ["id_attribute"] => 181
            ["id_custo_group"] => "3"
            ["price_impact"] => 4099.173554
        )

)
1
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            ["id_attribute"] => 182
            ["id_custo_group"] => "1"
            ["price_impact"] => 4099.173554
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            ["id_attribute"] => 182
            ["id_custo_group"] => "2"
            ["price_impact"] => 4099.173554
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            ["id_attribute"] => 181
            ["id_custo_group"] => "3"
            ["price_impact"] => 4099.173554
        )

)
1
```

Notice that the id_attribute in the last array is different from the one in the source $export array. This happens only for the last nested array of the whole array.

I have no idea why that happens, so any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What is the issue ?

Comment: The issue the last "id_attribute" is 181 instead of 182 as the original array. This sound weird , can you please attach small code snipt that reproduce it?

Comment: Do note the extra `1` in your output is the default behavior of `print_r`, which output the variable immediatly. Ommit the `echo` or use `true` as 2nd argument to buffer the ouput, `echo print_r($data, true);`

Comment: tyr to echo the $key of the sub array, foreach ($export as $key => $attribute)

Comment: We need to see any code that interacts with `$export` before the echo/print_r-part.

Comment: Ok, I'll provide the code once I'm home from work.